# Join lines if character is missing

Tags: python, if-statement, join, line

I need to write in python that "if line ends with '=' and line before starts with number and does not end with '=' then join lines".

As suggested i am trying to use a definition but I am not familiar how to write it.

Comment: Hi, please read and follow [mcve] when posting questions.

Comment: is = the end of the line??

Comment: correct. @fazkan

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got 100% the criteria to join the line.
But, in the code bellow, you can adjust it easily:

```
def join_line(line):
    if line.endswith('=\n'):
        if line[-3].isdecimal():
            return True
    return False

with open('<your_file_here>','r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)-1):
    if join_line(lines[i+1]):
        lines[i] = lines[i][:-1] + ' '
with open('<your_output_file>', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```

EDIT: sorry, I thought you wanted to delete the lines. Now it is correct.
EDIT 2: persist output to file

Comment: Why the isdecimal() condition in join_line() function?

Comment: Otherwise the line `89577 46/// /0703 11704 35608 4//// 5////=` would be joined too

Comment: i think it does it. But could you help me to overwrite the text file.

Comment: Now it is saving to an output file

Comment: And what happens when the next line has something like 80///=

Comment: It won't join. As I said, the join criteria is not 100% explained. But the `join_line` function can be changed to work anyway you want. You can use it to cover that case too.

Comment: @edinho it does two things that I keep trying to stop them but I can't. That's why i took me long to reply. Firstly in combines the lines that start with AAXX whith the next line if it already ends with '='. It joins lines that both end with '='.

Comment: Do you mean "the algorithm should join the lines that start with AAXX"? Because on your example it doesn't. Lines that starts with AAXX stay the same way on your output. Maybe you should be able to describe the join rule completely. It is hard to understand the problem.

Comment: @edinho I updated my main question. I really like your approach with the definition. I have written above what I want the definition to do. I am sorry, i just started using python.